# How to pretend x64 vs x86

Tags: operating-systems

I'm on an x64 bit Windows 7 OS

I want to surf the internet pretending that I'm on x32 OS.
So that the websites will load x32 bit contents.
Specific case: I want to download some x32 bit apps, but all the sites only load x64 bit apps by default.

Any possibilities ??

Comment: Why? What's the logic behind this request? It feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me.

Comment: I've never seen a site **_only_** offer downloads according to the `User-Agent` header (the only information they have on this front). They've always offered a "_running something else?_" type link / button.

Answer (score 1):

Websites dont know the architecture you are running - they infer it from the UserAgent atring sent by your browser.

A solution is to get a plugin for your browser which allows you to set an alternative useragent string which reflects as coming from a 32 bit browser.  They are fairly easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

On 64 bit Windows 7 you can install and use Virtual PC to run a 32 bit instance of Windows in a VM. This will be a genuine 32 bit OS and browsers will announce themselves as such. This may be overkill to solve your problem but it is one route.

See [Will running Windows 32-bit virtual machine on 64-bit Windows 7 fix this issue?](https://superuser.com/questions/943020/will-running-windows-32-bit-virtual-machine-on-64-bit-windows-7-fix-this-issue) for a similar question.

Comment: While this is correct (and I upvoted) it is a bit overkill when @davidgo 's suggestion of modifying the user-agent string is much quicker and easier.  However for some things, like testing application behavior, running a 32bit VM is the best way to test.

Comment: @ivanivan I agree with you.